# Is there any way to get 'views.py' of pre-installed apps in django especially 'auth' app?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I got 403 Forbidden while loading my web page, and 
it says to ensure that 'The view function passes a request to the template's render method.'
also i tried all other solutions.
if there's any alternate solution please suggest.

PS: It works fine in firefox, no forbidden error. but not in chrome (i've ensured that it accepts cookies).

Comment: Hey there, it might be wise to mention what you have tried and provide a snippet of code where applicable. It'll help us help you.

Comment: We will need a bit more information. How are you routing to the views of the `auth` package (in other words: what have you placed in your main `urls.py`)?

Comment: When are you getting the error? What page are you trying to access? Does it allow you to log in to the site or is the error there for every page you try to access?